# Possible to update config options in Stripe with custom checkout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe and have created a [custom checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom), as per that page:

```
var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
  key: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  image: 'https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png',
  locale: 'auto',
  token: function(token) {
    // You can access the token ID with `token.id`.
    // Get the token ID to your server-side code for use.
  }
});

document.getElementById('customButton').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  // Open Checkout with further options:
  handler.open({
    name: 'some name',
    description: '2 widgets',
    currency: 'aud',
    amount: 2000
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});

// Close Checkout on page navigation:
window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
  handler.close();
});
```

However I am wondering if there is any way I can update the config options passed to `open` as I need to update the `amount` when the user makes a change.

...or is my best bet just re-initiating all or that part of it?

Whilst this code is in vanilla JavaScript I have changed it to jQuery on my end, so a jQuery solution would be preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to define simple your amount in a variable, and then modify the value of that variable as you take actions on your page which change the price.

```
// define an amount, you could always modify this later
var myAmount = 2000;

// when the submit button is clicked
document.getElementById('customButton').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      // Open Checkout with further options:
      handler.open({
        name: 'some name',
        description: '2 widgets',
        currency: 'aud',
        amount: myAmount
      });
      e.preventDefault();
});
```

One example you might find interesting, http://jsfiddle.net/ns2fezag/

Comment: Ahh good idea. :) Also, thanks for the example link - that's really cool!